# How can I only generate controller without view jspx files by Spring-Roo?

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-roo

I'm using Spring Roo to build my service layer, the layer needs json interface without jspx files. But I tried `controller Scaffold` or `controller all` all of them generate view layer. So my question, how can I generate controller layer without view to build a service project?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to just create a Controller Class without any views, use following command

```
controller class --class ~.domain.NameOfController
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a web service layer you can run something similar to:

service --interface ~.service.SomeEntityService --entity ~.domain.SomeEntity